# Redirect to outside Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a folder called "stats" on my server that I cannot access anymore because wordpress redirects it to the "Page not found". This folder has nothing to do with wordpress. I have searched for a solution but nothing seems to be working. I am using the theme elegant fusion.

For clarification, the folder is on the same level directory wise as "wp-admin", "wp-content", "wp-includes".

Does anyone know how I can access my folder without going through wordpress?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: yourdomainname.com/stats/filename.php did you try this ?

Comment: @wordpresser I did, it shows the redirect page for the wordpress theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable searach engine optimised permalinks is the answer.  I am thinking you must be using the default permalinks, by enabling seo permalinks in Settings->Permalinks in the backend will create (assuming permissions allow, if not you do it manually)  an .htaccess file in the root of your install like so;

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The two lines that will solve your problem are;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Which tell wordpress to ignore any url which is for an actual directory or file. Anything else gets rewritten by Wordpress.